# How to execute batch delete from multiple tables with batch size in spring boot jdbc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to delete from 6 tables and they have millions of records.. So I want to delete in batches. currently I use `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(deleteQueryArray)`

This may result in deadlock sometimes so I want to delete in batches of size x which will scale well.

Queries:

```
DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT 
WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT BE.STEP_EXECUTION_ID 
                            FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION BE 
                            JOIN BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT BEC ON BE.STEP_EXECUTION_ID = BEC.STEP_EXECUTION_ID  
                            WHERE LAST_UPDATED < '2020-11-01 00:00:00'), 

DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION 
WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID 
                           FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION 
                           WHERE LAST_UPDATED < '2020-11-01 00:00:00'), 

DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS 
WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID 
                           FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  
                           WHERE LAST_UPDATED < '2020-11-01 00:00:00')

DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION 
WHERE LAST_UPDATED < '2020-11-01 00:00:00'

DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE 
WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID NOT IN (SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID 
                              FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION)
```

So, I see 2 approaches.

1. find max job ID from the job execution eligible for delete and then divide it by let suppose a factor of 10 and loop through 10 times to delete from 6 tables(Job execution and corresponding child table step records). using same batch update
2. Using spring batch update from every table use batch option to delete and provide batch size to Spring batch for batch deletion. I think this approach will take more time than approach 1.

Can someone please share your thought what is the best approach here
Thanks

Comment: Why does this result in a deadlock? Are you running those queries in a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

We have millions of data after every billing cycle and have sql procedure that have all the tables with FK references and iterating in for loop. This is getting called by a separate Job. I think solution in this case should be based on business operational activity and how frequently this needs to be executed .

Comment: This needs to get executed once a day. This is routine purging action of older data.